# the word "UPDATE" causes CMS page not to save Magento 1.9.4.2

Tags: cms, editor

Here's a strange one...

I'm editing my privacy policy page in CMS>pages and copy/pasting the text out of notepad++, then formating with the wysiwyg editor in magento, then cleaning up the html that the editor leaves dotted around.

I copy/pasted all the text and clicked "Save and Continue Edit" and after a pause of a few seconds I am returned to the list of CMS pages - if i then click the privacy policy to edit it again, the changes are not there.

So, i thought there must ba an odd character that i've not spotted, a line to long or some formatting issue that's causing the problem so I began pasting in the text bit by bit until i found the part that was causing it not to save.

when I narrowed that down more and more and even typed the text directly in to the editor rather than pasting it it turns out that the word "update" cause the edit to fail!   "updat" and "updat e" are fine but if I put "update" ANYWHERE on the page, the edit will fail.

Comment: Sounds like the Magento protection for XSS (Cross-Site-Scripting) taking part of your saving process.

Comment: The fact that it is kicking you back to the list rather than the current page as "Save and Continue Edit" should do suggests that an exception is being thrown. Checking the Magento exception log and webserver error log may give you more specific info about what is happening.

Comment: took a look at the exception log and there is nothing in there...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to take a look into the tiny_mce setup.js located in

`js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js`

This file is the setup script for some of the XSS protection in Magento cms blocks and pages. As far as i know there are listed HTML element names, which are valid inside a CMS-block, others are getting removed.
I don't think that this is also for other keywords inside the block, but just for the tag-filter, but maybe this is a point to start researching for the problem.

Comment: thanks - took a look at the file and, sadly, its way beyond my knowledge ....  - I'll live without the word update for now :)